# Issue converting UK date into text (returns US format)?

Tags: excel, vba

I have recorded a macro that will convert a column of dates in UK format to text by using Text to Columns when recording it, but the text it returns is in US format. Text to Columns does the job when its outside of a macro so not sure why it wouldn't work when used in a macro.

Is there a way to have the text in UK format and not have it converted to US format? I believe the below is the relevant part:

````
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("E1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 2), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Columns("F:F").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("F1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 2), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Columns("A:P").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Xero Upload Template V2.xlsx").Activate
    Range("A4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste```
````

Comment: You could try changing `FieldInfo:=Array(1, 2)` to `FieldInfo:=Array(1, 4)`, to convert it to UK date format. Then have a separate `Columns(columno).NumberFormat = "@"` to convert it to text. It's not pretty but might be the best option if `.TextToColumns` doesn't do it properly.

Comment: Or at your paste action at the end, you could use a `.Pastespecial Format:="Text"` to convert it to text at that stage.

Comment: Why would anyone convert a real date into a text? Instead use number format to let the date look like what you want (but keep it a numeric date). If you convert a date into a text it becomes useless. Example: `02/03/2020` as text is completely useless because neither a humen nor a computer can tell if it is `dd/mm/yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy`. Therefore always use a real date and `NumberFormat` that. If it really needs to be text the only reliable text format is `yyyy-mm-dd` eg `2020-01-30` (according ISO 8601): https://xkcd.com/1179/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly then your data is in column 5 and 6 which you need to convert. Please try below code.

```
Dim c As Long

For c = 5 To 6   
Columns(c).TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, 
Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 5)
Columns(c).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
 Next c
```

Comment: Have you checked it?